# android ffmpeg command not working on HTC One M8 5.0.1

Tags: android, ffmpeg, command, htc-android

I have been creating an application that records video with audio through the ffmpeg library.
I also added ffmpeg.exe to raw files and am installing the binary inside project to run ffmpeg commands.

I have tested many commands that works on most of the devices but on HTC one M8 it is not giving any output nor error and i have no clue why.

The command is intended to take an input video.mp4 and create a slow-motion video output.mp4

The command is the following:

```
/data/data/com.vidcutter/cache/ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/markapp/TEMP_1436532617119/0.mp4 -filter:v setpts=3.0*PTS -q 0 -an /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/markapp/TEMP_1436532617119/1000.mp4
```

It runs smoothly on all devices ive tested on except the M8

Any help will be much appreciated!

PS: It works ironically smoothly on HTC One M7 lol

Comment: I think it is something regarding permissions
i tried using chmod 700 before executing the ffmpeg command line still with no result :(